# how to deal with escaped_fragment using scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

recently i used scrapy to scrape zoominfo then i test the below url

```
http://subscriber.zoominfo.com/zoominfo/#!search/profile/person?personId=521850874&targetid=profile
```

but some how in terminal, it changed like this

```
[scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://subscriber.zoominfo.com/zoominfo/?_escaped_fragment_=search%2Fprofile%2Fperson%3FpersonId%3D521850874%26targetid%3Dprofile>
```

I have added `AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED = True` in `setting.py` but the url still has `escaped_fragment`. I doubt that i haven't entered the right page i want.

The `spider.py` code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider


class LoginSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'zoominfo'
    login_page = 'https://www.zoominfo.com/login'
    start_urls = [
    'http://subscriber.zoominfo.com/zoominfo/#!search/profile/person?personId=521850874&targetid=profile',
    ]
    headers = {
        "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connectionc":"keep-alive",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",
    }   
    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        print "Preparing Login"
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            headers=self.headers,
            formdata={
            'task':'save',
            'redirect':'http://subscriber.zoominfo.com/zoominfo/#!search/profile/person?personId=521850874&targetid=profile',
            'username': username, 
            'password': password
        },
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter = True,
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login unsuccessful")
        else:
            self.log(":Login Successfully")
            self.initialized()
            return Request(url='http://subscriber.zoominfo.com/zoominfo/', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        base_url = 'http://subscriber.zoominfo.com/zoominfo/#!search/profile/person?personId=521850874&targetid=profile'
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = TutorialItem()
        divs = sel.xpath("//div[3]//p").extract()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath("//div[3]")
        print divs
        request = Request(base_url, callback=self.parse)
        yield request
```

thanks anyone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#!` == `_escaped_fragment_`

`_escaped_fragment_` is called ugly url and is mostly presented to web-crawler while real users get the pretty `#!` version. Either way they both mean the same thing and there shouln't be any different functionally.

See [google's ajax specification for this subject.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification#bidirectional-between--url-to-_escaped_fragment_-url)

Comment: so you mean that I have already entered the right page that I want? But why the url happened in the terminal is different from the one I want, including the '/' turns into '%2F', and also the '?' turns into the '%3F'.

Comment: @PeterTsung because all of sensitive characters after `#!` are being escaped since they are not part of the url, in other words those are bits meant not for your browser, but for the websites server.

Comment: So you mean that I have already entered the right page that i want, though the url in terminal is different from that one been post in the code ?

Comment: but why when i request the url in the terminal then the outcome was home page, which was after login session and different from the content shown in the page that been request by the url that post in the code ?

Comment: is there a Solution to scrap an url containing !# ?