# Scrapy response url not exatly the same as the one i defined on start urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider i give it this url `https://tuskys.dpo.store/#!/~/search/keyword=dairy milk`

However when i try to get the url in scrapy parse method the url looks like `https://tuskys.dpo.store/?_escaped_fragment_=%2F%7E%2Fsearch%2Fkeyword%3Ddairy%2520milk`

**Here is a demo code to demonstrate my problem**

```
import scrapy
class TuskysDpoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Tuskys_dpo"
    #allowed_domains = ['ebay.com']
    start_urls = ['https://tuskys.dpo.store/#!/~/search/keyword=dairy milk']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{'url':response.url}
```

**results:** `{"url": "https://tuskys.dpo.store/?_escaped_fragment_=%2F%7E%2Fsearch%2Fkeyword%3Ddairy%2520milk"}`

**Why is my scrapy response url not exactly the same as the url i defined and is there a way to go around this?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `response.request.url` because you are redirected from your start url, so `response.url` is the url you are redirected to.

Comment: I did try that...it doesn't work. You still get the `*_escaped fragments_*`...it has something to do with  the `!#`  in the url. I opted in reconstructing the URL from the `response.url`

Comment: Oh, it is not redirection, I see it now. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651100/how-to-deal-with-escaped-fragment-using-scrapy